# open all folds in project.vim by default

Tags: vim

When opening the project window for the first time in vim, all folds are closed. I find this very annoying. Is there any way to have them all open by default? I've read trough all of the documentation for project.vim but couldn't find a setting for this.

Comment: Does the project.vim buffer have a specific filetype?  If so, you could set foldlevel extremely high with an autocmd.

Comment: Like Al mentioned in his answer, you can use an autocmd with the default project filename (.vimprojects). The problem with that is that the autocmd seems to get executed before the project contents are loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about an autocmd?

Assuming you use the default projects filename, you could do something like this:

```
autocmd BufEnter .vimprojects silent! %foldopen!
```

If you want to maintain the cursor position, you could either clobber a mark or use a variable:

```
autocmd BufEnter .vimprojects let PreFoldPosition = getpos('.') | silent! %foldopen! | call setpos('.', PreFoldPosition)
```

**Edit**

It seems that project.vim creates the buffer and then adds the contents.  As a result of this, the autocmds above only work on the second and subsequent times the project window is opened.  The only way I know of to get round this is to edit `project.vim` and put `silent! %foldopen!` near the end of the function `s:Project(filename)`.  It might be worth sending an email to the author and asking whether he could add a means of doing this (with an option) in the standard distribution.

Comment: Now I get the message
    E490: No folds found

Comment: Presumably you have no folds in your projects file at the moment.  I've added `silent!` to the suggestion to remove the error message in this case.

Comment: Okay, if I close the project window and open it again the command works as expected. Seems like the autocmd is executed before the project is loaded..

Comment: Having just had a look through project.vim, it looks like it creates the window then reads in the contents, rather than opening the file.  I think the only way you'd get round this (that I can think of) is to edit project.vim and put `silent! %foldopen!` near the end of the function `s:Project(filename)`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. Should I flag this answer as correct even trough the real answer is in the comments?

Comment: I've added the details of the final approach into the answer itself (in the spirit of http://tinyurl.com/2acv5t6)

Answer (score 4):

Put this in your .vimrc to set all folds to open when you open a file:

```
set foldlevel=99
```

That will cause all 99th level folds to be closed, which I hope is none of them. If you have more than 99 levels of folds, you have a 99 problems joke.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is kind of old, but another solution is to create a function in your .bashrc (or similar) to do the following:

```
vim +"Project $1" +'silent! %foldopen!'
```

For instance, in my .bashrc, I have the following:

```
export PROJECT_DIR="$HOME/devel/projects"

project()
{
    if test -z "$1"
    then
        echo "Usage: project <project name>"
    else
        if [ ! -e "$PROJECT_DIR/$1" ]
        then
            echo "Project not found. Available projects:"
            find $PROJECT_DIR/* | xargs -l basename
        else
            vim +"Project $PROJECT_DIR/$1" +'silent! %foldopen!'
        fi
    fi
}

_project()
{
    local cur
    local PROJECTS=`find $PROJECT_DIR/projects/* | xargs -l basename`
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$PROJECTS" -- $cur ) )
}
complete -F _project project
```

Which allows me to simply issue the 'project' command and tab-complete the name.